# I am trying to store a future date" DateTime _eventDate;" in cloud firestore,,but in the output I am not getting the user picked date

Tags: flutter, datetime, datepicker

I am trying to store a future date" DateTime  _eventDate;" in cloud firestore,,but  in the output I am not getting the user picked date

my codes in  add_entry.dart are as

```
 class _AddEventPageState extends State<AddEventPage> {
    
      DateTime _eventDate;


 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    _eventDate = DateTime.now();


     const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text("Date (YYYY-MM-DD)"),
                    subtitle: Text("${_eventDate.year} - ${_eventDate.month} - ${_eventDate.day}"),
                    onTap: ()async{
                      DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(context: context, initialDate: _eventDate, firstDate: DateTime(_eventDate.year-5), lastDate: DateTime(_eventDate.year+5));
                      if(picked != null) {
                        setState(() {
                          _eventDate = picked;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
    
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),


 //Controller Update
   
      _eventDate = DateTime.now();
```

My code in event.dart is as follows:

```
class EventModel extends DatabaseItem{
 
  final DateTime eventDate;

  EventModel({this.id, this.eventDate}):super(id);

  factory EventModel.fromMap(Map data) {
    return EventModel(
 
      eventDate: data['event_date'],
    );
  }

  factory EventModel.fromDS(String id, Map<String,dynamic> data) {
    return EventModel(
      id: id,
    
      eventDate: data['event_date'].toDate(),
    );
  }

  Map<String,dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      
      "event_date":eventDate,
      "id":id,
    };
  }
}
```

My code in product_provider.dart are as follows

```
class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  DateTime _eventDate;



  String _productId;
  var uuid = Uuid();

  //Getters

  DateTime get eventDate => _eventDate;

  //Setters
    set changeDate(DateTime eventDate){
    _eventDate =  eventDate;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  loadValues(Product product){
    _eventDate = DateTime.now();
   // _eventDate = DateTime.parse(product.eventDate);
    _productId=product.productId;
  }

  saveProduct() {
    print(_productId);
    if (_productId == null) {
      var newProduct = Product(

          eventDate : _eventDate,


          productId: uuid.v4());
      firestoreService.saveProduct(newProduct);
    } else {
      //Update
      var updatedProduct =
          Product(
              eventDate : _eventDate,
               productId: _productId);
      firestoreService.saveProduct(updatedProduct);
    }
  }

  removeProduct(String name){
    firestoreService.removeProduct(name);
  }

}
```

Please fix my issue so that my output  evenDate should be the user picked dated or selected date.

Comment: can i see your json parsing model?

Comment: class EventModel extends DatabaseItem{
  final String id;
  final DateTime eventDate;
 EventModel({this.id, this.eventDate}):super(id);

  factory EventModel.fromMap(Map data) {
    return EventModel(
      title: data['title'],
       eventDate: data['event_date'],
    );
  }

  factory EventModel.fromDS(String id, Map<String,dynamic> data) {
    return EventModel(
      id: id,
        eventDate: data['event_date'].toDate(),
    );
  }

  Map<String,dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
            "event_date":eventDate,
      "id":id,
    };
  }
}

Comment: I have used  or imported import 'package:firebase_helpers/firebase_helpers.dart';

Comment: Is it the one you are asking for ? Please reply soon as I have to implement in my current project to store the date and retrieve back.

Comment: you are using _eventDate = DateTime.now(); and you haven't implemented any date picker or something for the user to select date. How do you expect to use the user selected date ? _eventDate will by default take the current Date and Time as you have specified is as DateTime.now();

Comment: No I have used date picker as       you can see in my add_entry.dart provided above and my callender is showing , able to select the date but in the output it is remaining as current date. Please suggest me where and what changes to be done?                  so I have to put _eventDate = ?

Comment: if you are using setState((){_eventDate = picked }), then why are you again assigning _eventDate = DateTime.now();   , assigning new value will overWrite the _eventDate. I think this is the problem, do not assign new value to _eventDate after setState.

Comment: Ok thank you I will change as  update you.,At which places exactly do you want me to change  . Is it   at void init state  ?

Comment: yeah do let me know. If it dosen't work

Comment: No if I try to set my _eventDate to DateTime or  eventDate etc or any modifications in my add_entry.dart file etc My widget screen is getting blank, if I keep it as before, my eventDate is picking i s chaging in the inoput datepicker callendar in output, retrieved date it coming as null.

Comment: have you properly initialize the datePicker with initState and disposed it ?

Comment: no in dispose I did not used any shall I use      DateTime _eventDate;

Comment: can u please give expalin whole  coding with an example  add_entry.dart , model.dart, vview_entry.dart, product_provider.dart and  ,entry.dart etc.

Comment: No  not working still can you please explain with some example to store future date in clud firestore  . I want to show Date which the user selects as aList Item in the form

Comment: please consider taking proper lectures on this topic, I won't be able to explain it right here, as it is such a vast topic, there are plenty of websites and youtube videos to learn it . hope you understand :)